# The system forgot that the user has a name

Tags: support, comments, display-names

Have a look at [this comment](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5152/why-dont-we-just-ban-homework-altogether#comment14890_5152)

[image]

[Chat seems to not find his username as well](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12001395#12001395) (meaning that the problem has propagated to the API), however, [this is the user who commented and he has a nonempty username](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1708/user1708?tab=activity&sort=comments).

The comment probably has a corrupted `UserDisplayName` field, since the API is affected as well.

Looking closer, this is the case with all of his comments on meta ad main.

Just ten minutes after the comment, the user edited his name to something else, which was reverted by a diamond 3 and a half hours after that. I suspect this to be a race condition with some sort of caching, not sure.

Comment: Bug: [status-sklivvz] is not a proper status tag.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn It's the status tag to be used when the bug can only be [status-reproduced] if Sklivvz is the one breaking things. Which means that it's _sort of_ [status-bydesign] and/or [status-norepro]. One day Sklivvz will ragequit (as an active user on MSO and Physics Meta _and_ Skeptics, that's inevitable), and the bug will disappear, so it's [status-planned]. We can trust Sklivvz not to break things the same way again, so it's _almost_ [status-completed]. So ... yeah, [status-sklivvz]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He actually *didn't* have a username. Now he does.

Comment: Huh? [He did have a username](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/history/1708).

Comment: So far as I can tell, it was empty.

Comment: (For the record: On discussing in TL I realized what the problem was, it's a rare enough edge case for it not to need fixing)

Comment: Are you sure that it wasn't unicode?

Comment: Seems unlikely, given how the user page rendered a default name for him.

Comment: @TravisJ Nope. Edge case. Not something that can be abused by users.